# PHP проверка массива на пустоту

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, появилась паранойя.

Как надежнее проверять массив с важными данными, на пустоту?

```
if(!empty($arr)) {
  ..to do
}
```

Или же фильтровать массив от пустых значений, затем его проверять на empty:

```
if(!empty(array_filter($arr))) {
  ..to do
}
```

Comment: первого вполне достаточно.

Comment: нет, не достаточно. Нужно проверять

Comment: @Влад. тогда как-то конкретизируйте критерии, надо отталкиваться от вводных. плодить параноиков не стоит.

Comment: да, нужно знать на что проверять. И помнить что массив с елементами равными NULL например это не пустой массив. Это не параноя, а здравый смисл замечать такие места где могут быть потом проблемы если что пойдет не так.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно смотреть что вам нужно, если в масиве будет только один елеммент со  значением NULL то empty вернет FALSE.

```
$array = [NULL];
var_dump(empty($array));
```

вернет FALSE.

Но в то же время,

```
$a = NULL;
var_dump(empty($a));
```

вернет `TRUE`.

То есть PHP не идет рекурсивно вглубь массива и не проверяет значения массива, если там будут только NULL массив все равно будет считаться непустым.

Твой способ так же плохой для отсеивания NULL, FALSE, '';

Смотри что будет

```
$arr = [
    NULL,
    'key' => [
        NULL
    ],
];

var_dump(empty(array_filter($arr)));
```

будет FALSE. Но наверное тебе нужно TRUE :)

Можно использовать [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php), но все зависит от задачи.